# PasswordCredential BackgroundTransfer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, credentials

Im creating a new BackgroundTransfer and adding Server Credentials:

```
PasswordCredential webdavLogin = new PasswordCredential();
webdavLogin.UserName = ServerSettings.Values["serverUsername"].ToString();
webdavLogin.Password = ServerSettings.Values["serverPassword"].ToString();
uploader.ServerCredential = webdavLogin;
```

Now the problem is, everytime i run the BackgroundTransfer, the following exception raises:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070565
The maximum number of secrets that may be stored in a single system has been exceeded
```

I searched the CredentialStore, but it is empty, there are no Credentials stored.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem. The **BackgroundTransfer** is obviously adding them into the **PasswordVault** itself.  You could try not creating a new instance of **PasswordCredential** but ensuring it is in the **PasswordVault** (adding if it is not there) and retrieving it.  This might stop the *BackgroundTransfer* adding it in multiple times.  You still need to watch the maximum number of credentials that can be stored on the phone... some weird number like 161 comes to mind, but I'm not sure.

Alternatively, what I did as I only required basic authentication, was to create the request header with the authentication details myself (an instance of **BackgroundUploader** has a method *SetRequestHeader* that you can use).

```
    var uploader = new BackgroundUploader
    {
        //ServerCredential = new PasswordCredential {UserName = uploadUser.Name, Password= uploadUser.Password}
    };
    var authHeader = Headers.GetAuthorizationHeader(uploadUser.Name, uploadUser.Password);
    uploader.SetRequestHeader(authHeader.Key,authHeader.Value);

    KeyValuePair<string, string> GetAuthorizationHeader(string username, string password)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Authorization, "Basic " + EncodeToBase64(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password)));
    }

    string EncodeToBase64(string toEncode)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncode);
        var returnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Given my scenario, this was easier than managing credentials through the **PasswordVault**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My problem is, i need to use Digest auth, so i need to use the credentials with PasswordCredentials. I tried to retrieve them, but as i set them in my first post, there are no credentials to retrieve, i dont know why. I have added a function to count the credentials stored in PasswordVault, but it gives me back nothing (0).

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 20 outstanding operations with credentials.

If you believed there are no operations running at the time, chances are there are 10 forgotten or broken operations in the cache. `AttachAsync()` all of them and cancel them immediately.

Here is an example:

```
private async Task CancelAll()
{
    // Get all running operations.
    var downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(downloads.Count);

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var download in downloads)
    {
        var task = download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    try
    {
        // Cancel all the operations. It is expected they will throw exception.
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("All canceled!");
}
```

Then, schedule the new operations with `DownloadOperation.StartAsyn()`.