# Background Uploader for Windows Phone is complaining about Maximum number of secrets

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, background-task

While trying to upload Log files to server using the BackgroundUploader class, we are seeing the below issue.

*The maximum number of secrets that may be stored in a single system has been exceeded. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070565)*

**Environment Details:**

- Visual Studio 2013
- C#
- Windows Embedded Handheld Phone 8.1 application

Initially few files would be uploaded, but once we see this exception the files are no longer uploaded to the server.

We are providing the credentials using PasswordCredential class.

Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178552/passwordcredential-backgroundtransfer

Comment: One answer is about Background Downloader, which is not I'm looking for. :(

Second answer is about using Basic Authentication, which I don't think will work for me :(

Comment: The concept is the same.

Comment: var downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
Debug.WriteLine(downloads.Count);

Above line always return Zero count and not able to cancel/restart any pending uploads.

Comment: Did you use a `BackgoundTransferGroup` when starting the previous downloads?

Comment: Yes, I have used but with no luck.

Comment: What I mean is that if you used `BackgroundTransferGroup`, then you have to use `GetCurrentDownloadsFromTransferGroupAsync()` instead of `GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()`.

Comment: Opened a service ticket for the issue. Looks to be more of a device dependant